# return closures but cannot infer type

Tags: rust, closures

When learning rust [closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html#refactoring-with-closures-to-store-code),I try Like Java return "A Function"

```
fn equal_5<T>() -> T
    where T: Fn(u32) -> bool {
    let x:u32 = 5;
    |z| z == x
}
```

But when i use it

```
let compare = equal_5();
println!("eq {}", compare(6));
```

Build error

```
11 |     let compare = equal_5();
   |         ------- consider giving `compare` a type
12 |     println!("eq {}", compare(6));
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
   |
   = note: type must be known at this point
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/trait/impl_trait.html

Currently `T` simply *describes* a type, which in this case implements the `Fn` trait. In other words, `T` isn't a concrete type. In fact with closures, it's impossible to declare a concrete type because each closure has it's own unique type (even if two closures are exactly the same they have different types.)

To get around directly declaring the type of the closure (which is impossible) we can use the `impl` keyword. What the impl keyword does is convert our description of a type (trait bounds) into an invisible concrete type which fits those bounds.

So this works:

```rust
fn equal_5() -> impl Fn(u32) -> bool {
    let x:u32 = 5;
    move |z| z == x
}

let compare = equal_5();
println!("eq {}", compare(6));
```

One thing to note is we can also do this dynamically. Using boxes and the `dyn` trait. So this also works, however incurs the associated costs with dynamic resolution.

```rust
fn equal_5() -> Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> bool> {
    let x:u32 = 5;
    Box::new(move |z| z == x)
}

let compare = equal_5();
println!("eq {}", compare(6));
```

Comment: Heheh I think we submitted answers at the same time.  You're is more detailed though

Comment: For reference, the RFC which describes much of what `impl` traits are today: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1522-conservative-impl-trait.md

Comment: transistor: oh ha i see we did :P

Answer (score 1):

The compiler seems to be complaining that it's expecting a type parameter but finds a closure instead.  It knows the type, and doesn't need a type parameter, but also the size of the closure object isn't fixed, so you can either use `impl` or a Box.  The closure will also need to use `move` in order to move the data stored in `x` into the closure itself, or else it wont be accessible after `equal_5()` returns, and you'll get a compiler error that `x` doesn't live long enough.

```
fn equal_5() -> impl Fn(u32) -> bool {
    let x:u32 = 5;
    move |z| z == x
}
```

or

```
fn equal_5() -> Box<Fn(u32) -> bool> {
    let x:u32 = 5;
    Box::new(move |z| z == x)
}
```